# Agile release management tools

Tags: agile-processes, agile-project-management, continuous-deployment

What is better tool for agile projects with respect to continuous deployment - [Go](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/go-agile-release-management) from ThoughtWorks or [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) from JetBrains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Petr,

I think Go has more of a formal idea of a deployment pipeline attached to a build. In that, they're conceptually like my employer's tool [AnthillPro](http://www.urbancode.com/html/products/anthillpro/default.html) than TeamCity where a deployment is modelled as a different build type. If you wanted to separate your build and deployment processes into separate tools, Daniel's company (nolio) has a deploy only tool, so do we, (uDeploy) http://www.UrbanCode.com.

Cheers,

Eric